# How to use Jquery to loop through the li elements below, and click all of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use Jquery to loop through all of li elements like below:

I know by using "each" can loop through all the elements, but I dont know why I cant get them.

Can someone give me some ideas about this, or let me know how to click all of the `<li>` elements within the `<ul>` element.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="test"> 
    <li ct-tracking="FiltpickupType" ct-tracking-value="Test:1">
        <span>Test 1</span>
    </li> 
    <li ct-tracking="FiltpickupType" ct-tracking-value="Test:2">
        <span>Test 2</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: <ul class="test">
  <li ct-tracking="FiltpickupType" ct-tracking-value="Test:1"><span>Test 1</span></li>
  <li ct-tracking="FiltpickupType" ct-tracking-value="Test:2"><span>Test 2</span></li>
</ul>

Comment: you can just use `$('ul li').on('click', function(){ // your code here });`

Comment: So, if I do this, all the <li> elements will be clicked?

Comment: @JaromandaX i thought he wanted to click the `li` elements within the `ul`

Comment: For example, I use  $("li[ct-tracking='FiltpickupType']").each(function(){  $(this).click();})   But, only the first <li> element clicked.  What I want to do is click all the <li> elements

Comment: @JaromandaX why is it wrong? the handler will add a click event on all the li's so what is wrong with that?

Comment: you can use this https://jsfiddle.net/cwaq7gd2/ @TaotaoFeng

Comment: @Sushil Yep, this is what I want to realize. But, I know how to show the html content. But, when I changed to click, I mean I want to realize the click event, not just showing html content. Then the code does not response

Comment: I don't get you. you don't want to show the content? what do you want to show then?

Comment: @Sushil, I want to click all the <li> elements

Comment: u want to click all the `<li>` elements together at once?

Comment: @Sushil, yes... lolz

Comment: oh. ok. let me update my code

Comment: how about this https://jsfiddle.net/cwaq7gd2/2/ @Taotaofeng

Comment: @Sushil Cool, this is what I want to realize. Thanks

Comment: let me post this as an answer. please mark it if it helped u.

Comment: I've addded my answer @TaotaoFeng. please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple:

```
$(".test li").click();
```

jQuery by itself will run the click for every element in the resulting query.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kk2er5vz/

Comment: sorry, only the first li will be clicked if I do like this

Answer (score 3):

you can add an `onclick` event in your `<li>`

```
<ul class="test"> 
    <li ct-tracking="FiltpickupType" ct-tracking-value="Test:1" onclick='alert($(this))'>
        <span>Test 1</span>
    </li> 
    <li ct-tracking="FiltpickupType" ct-tracking-value="Test:2" onclick='alert($(this))'>
        <span>Test 2</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

and in you js code you can just write.

```
$(function(){

    $('.test li').each(function(index, element){        
      //console.log($(element).click());
      $(element).click();      
  });

});
```

here's a working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwaq7gd2/2/)

Comment: Cool, actually, I found a new way to click all the elements, and works very well on my project. I got what you mean, and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I used the for (var i =0; i < $("ul li").length; i ++) {$("ul li").eq(i).click();}

Comment: that's not the right approach @TaotaoFeng. you are looping through all the elements of the array and then again inside the loop you're using the same element by adding an `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take control during the click process, you can use `each` function to iterate through the items and click each one:

```
$(".test li").each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).click();
});
```

Comment: Thx, but if I do this, only the first one will be clicked.

Comment: Use this same piece of code to add an `on click` listener to both li and then run the code again. You will see that it will click on both elements.